# Error in MuPAD command: An arithmetical expression is expected. [exp]

Tags: matlab, mupad

I wanted to write the expression given by:

[image]

In this `calculate_dk` and `calculate_T` are functions having input arguments `ii` and `jj`. I wanted to maximize this equation with respect to `theeta` variable. But, **I am unable to form required expression** for this purpose. I tried using `symsum` function

```
syms ii jj
F = symsum(symsum(nchoosek(15,ii-1)*nchoosek(15,jj-1)*exp(theeta*calculate_dk(ii-1,jj-1) + sigmaa*calculate_T(ii-1,jj-1)), jj, 1, 16),ii,1,16);
```

But its giving the error

> Error using mupadmex Error in MuPAD command: An arithmetical
>   expression is expected. [exp] Error in sym/privUnaryOp (line 845)
>   Csym = mupadmex(op,args{1}.s,varargin{:});
>
> Error in sym/exp (line 6)
>  Y = privUnaryOp(X, 'symobj::map',
>   'exp');
>
> Error in Acuna_model_funct (line 24)
>  F =
>   symsum(symsum(nchoosek(15,ii-1) * nchoosek(15,jj-1) * exp(theeta *
>   calculate_dk(ii-1,jj-1)+ sigmaa * calculate_T(ii-1,jj-1)), jj, 1,
>   16),ii,1,16);

Please help me to **form an equation** so that i can optimize it (maximize it with respect to theeta).

Comment: Make your expression runnable. Is the question about "optimization" (no idea what that means in this context) or about the error? Provide the *entire* error message.

Comment: I just want the valid expression to be returned in F, so that i can  optimize it with respect to theeta